# Is it possible to get the type of an uninstantiated variable in Java?

Tags: java, oop, pointers, object

Is it possible to get the type of a variable that is declared (but not instantiated) in Java? 
for example:

```
public class Foo {

     FooTwo foo2;
     FooTwo foo3;
     FooThree foo4;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         if (foo2.getClass() == foo3.getClass()) {
             System.out.println("foo2 is the same type as foo3");
         }
         if (foo3.getClass() == foo4.getClass()) {
             System.out.println("foo3 is the same class as foo4");
         }
     }
}
```

With output:

```
foo2 is the same type as foo3
```

obviously the method `getClass()` does not work on an uninstantiated variable, so this code does not function. I am assuming that the information I am looking for is stored somewhere in the variable (pointer?) for type safety, and that it may be accessible. **Is it possible to Achieve this comparison?**

the reason:
I have a class with several declared variables. These variables are supposed to point to objects stored in an ArrayList in another class. I am trying to create a method that will take an initialized (but uninstantiated) variable as a parameter, scan the arraylist for an object matching the type of the initialized variable, and set the variable to the object (Make the variable point to the object).

ALSO: The point of the system is to remove coupling in the constructor of the class. The objects cannot be instantiated immediately or in the constructor.

Comment: What is the use case for this? In what situation do you not know the declared type of the variables?

Comment: Review your terminology. _Instantiation_ is something that applies to class types and which produces an instance. A variable is not an instance.

Comment: I will edit the question and ad a little context!
and your right, i'm afraid my terminology is probably all off base :/ what is the correct term for what I am referring to?

Comment: I'd just call it a null variable (or null field if you want to be specific), I assume it doesn't matter if it's been set to null or always been null. But the use case would definitely be good as I can't think of a situation in which it wouldn't be obvious, at compile time

Comment: Could you add the classes FooTwo and FooThree?

Comment: I edited the question. I am basically trying to automate the assignment of declared variables. I could obviously copy and past some code for each, but if this is possible it would simplify the class.
@MatthewC FooTwo and FooThree have no code and are just representative of different types.

Comment: [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html) definitely feels like the way to go with this. Be aware that reflection is a bit of a dark art: powerful but dangerous. Use it, but use as little of it as possible

Comment: You can't take a _variable_ as a parameter. Parameters are passed by value. And the parameter's type will be whatever you declare the parameter to be.

Comment: I ask because I want to know if they inherit from Foo or if FooThree inherits from FooTwo because the naming convention they have follows the same style used is similar to examples of code that do just that.

Comment: hmm I will definitely look into reflection. Sounds like it would be fun to play around with. 
@MatthewC I understand now! None of the Foos in this example inherit from the other.
So the answer I am seeing is that Java, by its nature, doesn't really support an approach like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start with, you need to be aware of the difference between the *type* of an expression and the *runtime-type* of a value. Consider, for example, the following code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(list.getClass());
```

The above code prints `class java.util.ArrayList`, not `java.util.List<java.lang.String>`, because `getClass()` returns the runtime-type of the object that `list` refers to, not the type of `list` itself.

So it doesn't make sense to call `getClass()` on an uninitialized variable, because there's no value for it to return the runtime-type of.

---

> I am trying to create a method that will that will take an initialized (but uninstantiated) variable as a parameter, […] and set the variable to the object (Make the variable point to the object).

Since Java is a pass-by-value language, it doesn't expose a way to modify a variable that is passed in as a parameter. For example, consider this method:

```
public void doNothing(Object obj) {
    obj = "obj";
}
```

The above method does absolutely nothing. It has a local variable `obj`, which originally contains whatever reference is passed in, and then is changed to refer to the string `"obj"` instead; but this change has no effect, because nothing actually uses the local variable `obj` after that point. In particular, this method does not have any effect on whatever reference was passed in.

The closest you can get is to use reflection; if your method takes an instance of [type `Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), it can both examine the declared type of the field, and set the field to a value of its choosing.

Comment: 'it doesn't really expose a way to do this' that is more what I was looking for. So this is what I'm understanding:
Obviously, since Java is not dynamically typed, there is information within the declared variable that dictates what objects it can point to. Even though this information is there, the language does not provided a way to access it.
Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Eh, what? I think you misunderstood what that sentence is referring to. I've edited the answer to be more explicit.

Comment: @MikeJava if you can refer to a variable, you have to already know the type it's declared with, so you can just put that in directly...

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's true! that's what I will fall back on if this proposed method fails. What I am trying to do is automate this process. I will have many subclasses, all of which will have different declared variables to be assigned. If i can get a method that will assin these for me based on the type of the declared variable, I can avoid copying all that code.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using generics, then.  You cant refer to a local variable like that.

Comment: In my research on this answer I've come across the term metadata. Because you are suggesting reflection, is the type (not the runtime type) of an expression a form of metadata? (I've only just discovered the term so please excuse any incompetency)(I'm trying hard to understand this answer)

Comment: @LouisWasserman You may be right on the generics, but I can't quite see how it applies. Maybe make it an answer?

Comment: Reflection was the answer! I successfully implemented a method to achieve my goals. Thank you. If I remember, I will come back and edit the question for clarity.

Comment: @MikeJava: You're welcome! Re: "I will come back and edit the question for clarity": I don't think you should do that. It doesn't look like anyone found your question unclear -- if they had, they would have downvoted and/or voted to close -- and if you edit it too much based on what you've learned since writing it, you risk changing it into a significantly different question that would no longer be useful to people who haven't already learned what you've just learned. Your question has four upvotes, indicating that people find it useful as-is.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar using reflection. Here is an example code snippet. But may be there is a better way to solve your problem if you explain your use case in a bit more in detail.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Foo {

    static FooTwo foo2;
    static FooTwo foo3;
    static FooThree foo4;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        try {
            Field foo2Field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("foo2");
            Field foo3Field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("foo3");
            Field foo4Field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("foo4");

            if (foo2Field.getType().equals(foo2Field.getType())) {
                System.out.println("foo2 is the same type as foo3");
            }
            if (foo3Field.getType().equals(foo4Field.getType())) {
                System.out.println("foo3 is the same class as foo4");
            }

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO handle this if this can happen
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO handle this appropriately
        }

    }

}

class FooTwo {

}

class FooThree {

}
```

Comment: ooooh that is interesting... and it might just work.

Comment: This worked! Reflection is very cool. Your answer helped me to understand what is going on with reflection and answered my question, but the other answer, even though I didn't get it right away, also answered my question, with a little more detail on the inner workings of the language. So I will pick that answer, but thank you for your time!