# How to check type of a variable in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, types

I have seen many questions with similar title on StackOverflow but all those answers seem to suggest the `getClass().getSimpleName()` method. The problem is I don't wanna know the type of value that the variable holds, I am interested in the type of variable itself. In the following code, I want to print `Object`, not `String`:

```
Object ob = "Some String";
System.out.println(ob.getClass().getSimpleName()); // prints "String"
```

Given that the type of variable would be a super type of the value that it holds, I can check if the value is `instanceof` some class. But `instanceof` will return true for all the super classes up until we reach Object in the hierarchy. Is there a way to specifically check the type of variable?

There might not be any practical use cases for this in production code, but knowing the variable type may make generics easier to practice. Consider this method:

```
public static <T> void test (T a, T b) {

}
```

We don't know what type the compiler infers when `test` is called with two different arguments. It might be helpful to print out what's `T` replaced with. We know that T is going to be replaced with the most specific type that both the arguments' type inherit from when the program is run. But if I were to print that type, I can't.

Comment: That you know at compile time, so it's constant at runtime.

Comment: Java supports runtime polymorphism so at runtime all references holds actual objects and hence there isn't any such way I guess

Comment: Additional to Sweeper: Since the type of the variable is known at compile time your statement should be `System.out.println(Object.class.getSimpleName())`. This seems to be trivial (or nonsense) - or can you specify your real problem?

Comment: In addition to what's already been said: note that if you pass this object to a method, that would require a new variable, so there wouldn't be a reference to the original variable there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the type of an uninstantiated variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208062/is-it-possible-to-get-the-type-of-an-uninstantiated-variable-in-java)

Comment: @CoronA The example given in the question is just for the sake of, you know, example. It is trivial here. But, while practicing with generics things might not be that trivial.

Comment: It would have been kind if you provided a non-trivial example. I cannot imagine any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of a local variable is only available in debugging information.

You can;

- compile with debugging information.
- read the byte code for the debugging information and work out which one you are looking for.

NOTE: You can see this information in your debugger at runtime without writing any code.

However, a much simpler solution is to write a program such that you don't need to know this. e.g. store the data in a field instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be able to go from an object to the "variable" that holds it (at least as far as I know). So, if `ob` in your example is a local variable, you can't get its *declared type*.

Considering that an object can be pointed to by *multiple variables* of *different **declared*** data types, it would be a weird endeavor to resolve the "declared" type of the object (this is just my opinion).

As long as the object exists, all that matters is its runtime, concrete type (which is accessible through `obj.getClass()`), something that provides access to its type hierarchy.

For objects stored in class member fields (assuming you know the field name), you can obtain the declared field type:

```
DeclaringClass.class
    .getDeclaredField("fieldName")
    .getType()
    .getSimpleName();
```